# cannot open imagesource with relative with relative path

Tags: c#, directory, imagebrush

I need some help with imagebrush
it only works with absolute directories
for example

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="bgimage" ImageSource="C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaSampleWPF\MediaSampleWPF\obj\Debug\image.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

works fine but this

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="bgimage" ImageSource="image.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

gives me this error - if I replace image.png with notexist.png it gives me an error before compilation, but if I gut image.png it does not, meaning that the image actually exists

```
IOException: Cannot locate resource 'image.png'
```

the image is in every single directory of the solution , like, literally, i opened every folder in the project solution and i put image.png, but it still say that the image does not exist
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to do this in XAML?
If so, have you tried adding the image to your project as a resource?
My example is using an image on a button, but it will work the same for a brush.
In the project, or in a project subfolder "Add Existing Item" via right-click with the mouse or from the Project menu.

Then you can use a relative path to the resource in the project.

[image: XAML snippet]

[image]

In the .csproj file it ends up as an XML entry that looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Images\IO-64-black.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```